# Two way communication between Database and Application

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, postgresql, database-design

One way communication, from app to db is well apparent. Is there a way that my db also communicate back to app/ middle tier, or multiple instances of middle tier or apps.
Can triggers be used for this purpose in conventional rdbms (sql server/postgres)?

Comment: postgres allows you to write function with wide choice of languages, so of course you can create such trigger. or notify listened channel. or so.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .NET based application, you can get notification back from SQL Server easily.

SQL Server service broker infrastructure, query notifications enables notification from database back to the application.

You can implement this in 3 ways.

1- Using `SqlNotificationRequest` class. [Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18130/Advanced-SQL-SQLNotificationRequest-Functiona)

2- Using `SqlDependency`. [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency)

3- Using `SqlCacheDependency` [Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/787483/Web-Caching-with-SqlCacheDependency-Simplified)

Comment: That is more a feedback back to app from db, how about db start the communication rather responding back.

Comment: what you want to communicate? You can have a continuous job running in your DB which will use sp_OACreate to notify your app by calling a service in your application.

Comment: I will like to communication as much asynchronous as possible than synchronous.

Comment: I want my database trigger to execute delegate in C#